# C, read by line

Tags: c, file, line

I'm making a RPG game in C, and I need to read from a single file. Having multiple files is very tedious. Like "health.dat", "energy.dat", "money.dat" etc. I want to put them into one "data.dat", is this possible?

I just want to read specific line from a file
If line 1 has "number 1", then it should go to the "a" variable, line 2 should go to the "b" variable, etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: You'll be the best person to answer your question. How we will be able to tell you without knowing the context?

Comment: do you want to put the content or the file into data.dat?

Comment: Your question title doesn't really have anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Sorry my English is bad, I just want to read specific line from a file
If line 1 has "number 1", then it should go to the "a" variable, line 2 should go to the "b" variable, etc.

Comment: you can use the fgets function to get the line.

Comment: Detailed explanation, please?

Comment: Just google "read line by line" or something like that and you'll get to know that `fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp)` reads a line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve what you describe using the [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) function as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const int MAX_LENGTH = 256;

int main (void)
{
    // Open the file
    FILE* file = fopen ("data.dat", "r");

    // Read the lines
    char a[MAX_LENGTH];
    fgets (a, MAX_LENGTH - 1, file);
    char b[MAX_LENGTH];
    fgets (b, MAX_LENGTH - 1, file);
    // ...

    // Close the file
    fclose (file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Set the `MAX_LENGTH` variable to the maximum expected length of a line in your file. You should also test [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) and [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) for returning `NULL`, as both are error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. 
you can use the array of pointers in the fgets function.

```
       char *fgets(char *s, int size + 1, FILE *stream);
```

`fgets (array,size + 1,stream);` 
where array is `*array[size];`

Comment: Incorrect, `array` has to be at least `size + 1` bytes long, since fgets reads at most size characters and then adds a terminating `'\0'` character. ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/))